# Can R script be embedded in Tableau to produce a data set?

Tags: r, tableau-api

I'm trying to use R as data source for Tableau.
Meaning - my script generates a data set and I'd like to run this script in Tableau to generate the data source instead of connecting to csv file.
This can be easily done by Power BI, yet don't see this kind of option in Tableau.
There's the option of using R script in calculations but that's only once data set is already loaded.

Is there a way or a workaround?
Thank you in advance,
Alex

Comment: R scripts can update Tableau files by unzipping them and replacing the internal csv file

Comment: Meaning Tableau can run R directly to generate the data set? How?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way for Tableau to initiate it which is why I left this as a comment not an answer. But an external R script triggered some other way can edit Tableau files as I explained for a similar effect